# PostgreSQL data directory configuration

Tags: postgresql, centos, systemd

I am using PostgreSQL for CentOS. And i changed the data directory to store PostgreSQL data on a different disk.

```
nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service

#Environment=PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/data
Environment=PGDATA=/data/pgsql/data
```

However, after installing the package update, the contents of the configuration file were changed back to the default settings.

Do I need to check the configuration file every time I install a package update later? Or is there a way to preserve the config file?

Comment: You should use `systemctl edit` to create an override file:  https://serverfault.com/a/840999/581635

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to deal with this:

1. the old way:

   You create a file `/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service` that contains

   ```
    .include /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service

    [Service]
    Environment=PGDATA=/data/pgsql/data
   ```
2. the new way:

   You create a directory `/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service.d` that contains a file named (for example) `pgdata.conf` with the contents

   ```
    [Service]
    Environment=PGDATA=/data/pgsql/data
   ```

Then notify `systemd` with

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

This configuration change will override the corresponding value from `/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service`, so the change will survive an upgrade.